# Generalisation of fundamental theorem of linear algebra

Tags: functional-analysis

Does something similar to "Fundamental theorem of linear algebra" hold for infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_linear_algebra

Comment: Not quite an answer, but the rank-nullity theorem is a special case of the First Isomorphism Theorem, which of course holds in wildly greater generality. Presumably you would want something with Hilbert spaces to replicate the orthogonality relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regarding the relations between the kernel and the image :**

Given a separable Hilbert space $(H,\langle.,.\rangle)$ and a bounded linear operator $A : H \to H$, we have that 
$$
\ker(A)={Im(A^*)}^{\perp}
$$
$$
\overline{Im(A)}=\ker(A^*)^{\perp}
$$
where $A^*$ denotes the adjoint of $A$ (a generalization of the notion of transpose). The result should also hold for an operator between two different Hilbert spaces $H_1 \to H_2$.

*Proof of the first equality* :

(*) Consider $x \in \ker(A)$ and $y \in Im(A^*)$. Rewriting $y$ as $y=A^*z$ for some $z \in H$, we have that

\begin{align}
\langle x,y \rangle &= \langle x,A^*z\rangle \\ &=\langle Ax,z\rangle \\ &=0
\end{align}
since $x \in \ker(A)$. Thus $\ker(A) \subset Im(A^*)^{\perp}$.

(**) On the other hand, take $x\in Im(A^*)^{\perp}$. Then for all $y \in H$,

\begin{align}
\langle Ax,y \rangle &= \langle x,A^*y \rangle \\ &= 0
\end{align}
since $A^*y \in Im(A^*)$. Therefore we must have 
$
Ax=0
$
so 
$x \in \ker(A)$, which completes the proof.

*Proof of the second equality* : Using the first equality, and noting that $(A^*)^*=A$, we have
$$
\ker(A^*)={Im(A)}^{\perp}
$$
Taking the orthogonal complement, we have that
$$
\ker(A^*)^{\perp}=(Im(A)^{\perp})^{\perp}=\overline{Im(A)}
$$
which completes the proof.

Comment: Nice, do we always know that these two subspaces is the whole space? I think I manged to prove that the initial space of $A$ is the range of $A^{*}$

Comment: @user21312 This may be of interest : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1051881/direct-sum-of-kernel-and-image-of-the-adjoint-operator?rq=1